# `git diff HEAD` always shows changes where actually shouldn't

Tags: git, git-diff

My git directory is totally clean, like this:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:18 monorepo % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
ruqi.shang@ 13:24 monorepo % git diff --stat
ruqi.shang@ 13:25 monorepo % git diff --cached --stat
```

But it shows changes with `git diff HEAD`:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:25 monorepo % git diff HEAD --stat
 npmrc.json   |    8 -
 package.json | 1062 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 files changed, 1070 deletions(-)
```

And the changes are like a ghost when compared with a commit, like this (file names are hidden):

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:25 monorepo % git diff HEAD^ --stat
 1.java                 |    4 +
 2.java                 |   38 +-
 3.java                 |    8 +
 4.java                 |    8 +
 5.java                 |   58 +++
 ...
 npmrc.json             |    8 -
 package.json           | 1062 ------------------------------------------------
 10 files changed, 199 insertions(+), 1073 deletions(-)
```

The two files it saids deleted are there:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:35 monorepo % ls -lah npmrc.json package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 ruqi.shang  staff   169B Sep 21 13:06 npmrc.json
-rw-r--r--  1 ruqi.shang  staff    35K Sep 21 13:06 package.json
```

They are not ignored either:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:41 monorepo % git check-ignore npmrc.json package.json
ruqi.shang@ 13:41 monorepo %
```

It's sober with this command:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:44 monorepo % git diff HEAD -- npmrc.json package.json
ruqi.shang@ 13:44 monorepo %
```

What's wrong with my repo?

I didn't run any other commands in other tabs... And I don't think there are other background processes that is doing the trick. I believe there must be something wrong with git. Maybe a bug?
My git version:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:26 monorepo % git --version
git version 2.40.0
```

I'm using MacOS

---

In case it's about case sensitivity of the file system:

```
ruqi.shang@ 11:25 monorepo % git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | grep -i package.json
package.json
ruqi.shang@ 11:25 monorepo % git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | grep -i npmrc.json
npmrc.json
ruqi.shang@ 11:25 monorepo %
```

---

To answer @LeGEC 's question:

```
ruqi.shang@ 13:50 monorepo % git ls-files -v package.json npmrc.json
H npmrc.json
H package.json
ruqi.shang@ 13:50 monorepo % git update-index --really-refresh package.json
ruqi.shang@ 13:50 monorepo % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Could it be that the two files have weird line endings? Like someone stored them as windows files, pushed them as windows files with CRLF and when you pull them git converts to LF and sees the CR as removed characters?

Comment: Are you on a case-insensitive filesystem? And does the repository perhaps contain the files in question multiple times under names that only differ in case?

Comment: I second j6t's comment: can you tell what OS you are using ? check `git ls-tree --name-only HEAD`, to see if the repo contains `package.json` and `Package.json` for example.

Comment: @LeGEC I'm using MacOS. It's not about case sensitivity. I've updated my question, appending the commands and result in the end.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl I don't think it's about the line ending because if I do a `git diff HEAD` (without the --stat), I'll the whole file was removed (whole file in red), not only about the line endings. You can also see it from the stats. Take the `package.json` as an example, stat says there are 1062 lines removed, not changed. So it can't be line endings.

Comment: two hocus pocus incantations: 1. check if there isn't a "skip worktree" or "assume unchanged" flag set on that specific flie: `git ls-files -v package.json` (lower case letter indicates "assume unchanged", `S` (lower or higher) indicates "skip worktree"), 2. run `git update-index --really-refresh package.json` and see if this updates the status to be coherent with the diff.

Comment: @LeGEC I've appended it at the end of the question. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Wild-assed guess: corrupt index?  It's surprising that `git diff` and `git diff HEAD` report different output, since they are documented as being the same (`HEAD` is default). Clearly `git diff` without a version takes some shortcut.  Since you have no staged changes, try just blowing away the index and regenerating it from the head commit `rm .git/index; git reset --hard`.

Comment: try Kaz' suggestion. Is the directory of your repo mounted from a regular local hard drive ? or is it a shared directory/network mount/...
also: is that directory located in a place managed by a cloud syncing service (e.g: iCloud or ownCloud) ?

Comment: dumb question: what is the actual content on disk ? is package.json an empty file ? is it 1062 lines long ? you pasted `git diff --stat` (<- which is good for asking the question :) ), I imagine `git diff package.json` displays the diff as if package.json's content had been completely deleted ?

Comment: BTW, don't do `git reset --hard`; make that just `git reset`. Otherwise, you might destroy contents irretrievably.

Comment: @Kaz LeGEC, j6t, I copied the whole monorepo to somewhere else with rsync only for debugging purposes, and it also reproduced in the new location. Then I followed Kaz's suggestion and the issue was solved. I'm curious about what happened; the original repo was still there for more experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion from a comment worked. I suspected a case of a corrupted index.

In a repository in which we have no working changes, and the index contains no staged changes to lose (is identical to the `HEAD` commit) we can just remove it:

```
rm .git/index
```

That leaves the repo in a funny state, so we quickly restore the index:

```
git reset --hard
```

Now is a `.git/index` again corresponding to `HEAD`.

---

Story time. I've run into a bad git index before. Well, not me, but a coworker who reported a strange problem: the `/bin/ls` utility started dumping core on the embedded target. I got pulled into the Slack conversation. I sent the coworker a build of `strace` for the target. That wasn't helpful other than confirming that the program was crashing fairly early on in its initialization, resulting in a short trace. I suggested comparing the SHA256 of the executable on the device and in the git repository (which contains a `rootfs` image with a `bin/` and `usr/bin/` and so on). The SHA256 sums matched. However, they did not match the value I calculated for the same file in my repo. His repo looked clean,though. I suggested that the only thing I can think of is that the git index must be corrupt, since the coworker's git installation was not reporting any differences with `git diff` or `git diff --cached`.  Indeed, removing the `.git/index`, doing a `git reset` and rebuilding the image fixed it.